# elasticsearch multi match on range

Tags: elasticsearch

i have the following data (example):

```
[
    {
        "name": "eli",
        "requests": [
            {
                "creation": "2016-09-07T00:00:00Z",
                "title": "something",
                "message": "lorem ipsum",
                "priority": 1
            },
            {
                "creation": "2016-09-07T00:00:00Z",
                "title": "something",
                "message": "lorem ipsum",
                "priority": 2
            },
            {
                "creation": "2016-09-07T00:00:00Z",
                "title": "something",
                "message": "lorem ipsum",
                "priority": 5
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "John",
        "requests": [
            {
                "creation": "2016-09-07T00:00:00Z",
                "title": "something",
                "message": "lorem ipsum",
                "priority": 1
            },
            {
                "creation": "2016-09-07T00:00:00Z",
                "title": "something",
                "message": "lorem ipsum",
                "priority": 2
            },
            {
                "creation": "2016-09-07T00:00:00Z",
                "title": "something",
                "message": "lorem ipsum",
                "priority": 1
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

and i can't seem to figure out what type of mapping to use for requests so that i can filter only users that have requests with priority gte 1 and lte 2
which means that the user eli will not show

- I've tried to create it as simple field and query as follows

  `{"query": {"bool": {"must": [{"range": {"requests.priority": {"gte": 1, "lte": 2}}}]}}}`
  but it still returned the user eli.
- so I've tried to set it as nested but still no go (with the following query)
  `{"query": {"bool": {"must": [{"nested": {"path": "requests","query": {"range": {"requests.priority": {"gte": 1,"lte": 1}}}}}]}}}`
  any help is appreciated

p.s. i'm unsure that multimatch is the correct term to use in my problem

Comment: I hope you can find the solution from here: http://www.codingworkspace.com/2016/08/elasticsearch-part-6-nested-queries.html and There are some bunch of series of soring and range tutorials here: http://www.codingworkspace.com/search/label/Elasticsearch

Comment: this doesn't relate to my problem, as i said, i need a dependent query that will check all of the objects to match my query and not one of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution I came with is to change my approach and filter out those who don't match my criteria in which elastic supports so an example request will look like 
`{"query": {"bool": {"must_not": [{"range": {"requests.priority": {"lt": 1, "gt": 2}}}]}}}`